# Errors while testing simple BPEL component in isolation

Tags: websphere, bpel, wid

Errors while testing simple *BPEL component* in isolation @wid 7.0.0.4

BPEL component has only one Java snippet containing a single line:

```
System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++" + input1);
```

At the same time, the Java components are working fine.

My configuration is follows:
Ubuntu 12.10 
WID 7.0.0.4 
WPS 7

```
[5/21/13 10:42:25:111 MSD] 0000024f HTM           I   CWTKE0044I: Originator becomes administrator of task Component1. Usually this happens, because no people assignment criteria is defined for the administrators of the task, or because its usage returns an empty set of users.
[5/21/13 10:42:26:215 MSD] 00000222 cem           W com.ibm.websphere.cem getEmitterFactory CEMEM0003E: The specified emitter factory was not found in JNDI. {0} 
[5/21/13 10:42:26:216 MSD] 00000222 LocalExceptio E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "invokeProcessSessionBean" on bean "BeanId(BPEContainer_qnode_server1#bpecontainer.jar#CScopeProvider, null)". Exception data: com.ibm.bpe.api.UnexpectedFailureException: CWWBA0010E: Unexpected exception during execution.
com.ibm.bpe.api.EngineStateObserverEventError: CWWBE0013E: An error occurred during the event handling of 'activityStarted' in the observer plug-in type 'com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.CEMStateObserverPlugin'.
com.ibm.websphere.cem.exception.EmitterFactoryCreationException: CEMEM0003E: The specified emitter factory was not found in JNDI. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: qcell/nodes/qnode/servers/server1, name: com/ibm/events/configuration/emitter/Default: First component in name events/configuration/emitter/Default not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0] 
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: qcell/nodes/qnode/servers/server1, name: com/ibm/events/configuration/emitter/Default: First component in name events/configuration/emitter/Default not found.
org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.handleNameNotFound(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:2519)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.getNextWsnOptimizedNamingContext(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:1270)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$3.run(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4738)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$3.run(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4733)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.retry(CommonHelpers.java:771)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.getTargetContext(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4732)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$LeafOperationData.<init>(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:5311)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.resolve_complete_info(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:2155)
    at com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming._NamingContextStub.resolve_complete_info(_NamingContextStub.java:538)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2809)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2805)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.retry(CommonHelpers.java:771)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.cosResolve(CNContextImpl.java:2803)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1802)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1761)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1512)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:644)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:166)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:180)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at com.ibm.websphere.cem.ECSEmitter$5.run(ECSEmitter.java:825)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:202)
    at com.ibm.websphere.cem.ECSEmitter.getEmitterFactory(ECSEmitter.java:822)
    at com.ibm.websphere.cem.ECSEmitter.getEmitter(ECSEmitter.java:905)
    at com.ibm.websphere.cem.ECSEmitter.<init>(ECSEmitter.java:138)
    at com.ibm.ws.monitoring.core.cei.ECSAccess.getECSEmitter(ECSAccess.java:108)
    at com.ibm.ws.monitoring.core.BaseMonitor.getECSEmitter(BaseMonitor.java:334)
    at com.ibm.bpe.monitor.MonitoredComponent.getECSEmitter(MonitoredComponent.java:248)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.EventHelper.getECSEmitter(EventHelper.java:107)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.ActivityInstanceEventTypeHandler.processBPELEvent(ActivityInstanceEventTypeHandler.java:1880)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.CEMSOPContextRestored.activityInstanceEvent(CEMSOPContextRestored.java:170)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.BpelStateObserverContextImpl.restoreContextAndFireActivityInstanceEvent(BpelStateObserverContextImpl.java:1455)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.CEMStateObserverPlugin.activityInstanceEvent(CEMStateObserverPlugin.java:444)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.BpelStateObserver.observe(BpelStateObserver.java:1562)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.BpelStateObserver.observeOrDelay(BpelStateObserver.java:1525)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.BpelStateObserver.activityStarted(BpelStateObserver.java:86)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelActivityState.setActivityState(BpelActivityState.java:469)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelActivityState.setActivityState(BpelActivityState.java:593)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelActivityState.setActivityState(BpelActivityState.java:117)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelActivityState.setActivityState(BpelActivityState.java:99)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelActivityKindScript.doActivate(BpelActivityKindScript.java:70)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelActivityStateInactive.activateOrSkip(BpelActivityStateInactive.java:280)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelEngineCore.continueControlLink(BpelEngineCore.java:291)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelContinueLinkMessage3.execute(BpelContinueLinkMessage3.java:88)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelEngine.onMessage(BpelEngine.java:1536)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.GenericAPIServicesImpl$7.run(GenericAPIServicesImpl.java:440)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.infrastructure.InfrastructureServicesSupportBean.runInCScopeTxClassLoaderContextsWithException(InfrastructureServicesSupportBean.java:167)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.infrastructure.EJSLocalStatelessInfrastructureServicesSupportBea_70e9f9d4.runInCScopeTxClassLoaderContextsWithException(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.infrastructure.InfrastructureServicesImpl.runInCScopeTxClassLoaderContextsWithException(InfrastructureServicesImpl.java:350)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.infrastructure.InfrastructureServicesImpl$2.run(InfrastructureServicesImpl.java:251)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.sca.AbstractBPCImplementationHandler.handleInvocationEnvironmentRequest(AbstractBPCImplementationHandler.java:197)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.sca.AbstractBPCImplementationHandler.processMessage(AbstractBPCImplementationHandler.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessageWithPCI(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:755)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessage(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:1607)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.ManagedMessageImpl.process(ManagedMessageImpl.java:980)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.webmodule.handler.WebModuleContextSwitchHandler.processMessage(WebModuleContextSwitchHandler.java:146)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessageWithPCI(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:766)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessage(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:1607)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.proxy.impl.ProxyInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandlerImpl.java:783)
    at $Proxy78.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.sca.InvocationEnvironmentProviderImpl.runInInvocationEnvironment(InvocationEnvironmentProviderImpl.java:158)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.infrastructure.InfrastructureServicesImpl.runInScaCScopeTxClassLoaderContextsWithException(InfrastructureServicesImpl.java:257)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.GenericAPIServicesImpl.bpc_onMessage(GenericAPIServicesImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.navigation.CScopeProviderBean$1.run(CScopeProviderBean.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:202)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.navigation.CScopeProviderBean.invokeProcessSessionBean(CScopeProviderBean.java:165)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.navigation.EJSLocalStatelessCScopeProvider_19c383f5.invokeProcessSessionBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.navigation.NavigationWorkObject4ContextSwitch.processV6EngineMessage(NavigationWorkObject4ContextSwitch.java:409)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.navigation.NavigationWorkObject4ContextSwitch.processNextMessage(NavigationWorkObject4ContextSwitch.java:302)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.navigation.NavigationWorkObject4ContextSwitch.run(NavigationWorkObject4ContextSwitch.java:142)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$RunProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:202)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:768)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.ExecutionContextImpl.go(ExecutionContextImpl.java:86)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.ProcessExecutionContextImpl$2.run(ProcessExecutionContextImpl.java:169)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:251)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.ProcessExecutionContextImpl.go(ProcessExecutionContextImpl.java:159)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.navigation.ProcessNavigationBean.processNextMessage(ProcessNavigationBean.java:345)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.navigation.EJSLocalStatelessProcessNavigation_0f2917d9.processNextMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.navigation.NavigationWorkObject4WorkMgrThread.run(NavigationWorkObject4WorkMgrThread.java:103)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$RunProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:224)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:495)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:131)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:89)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$DoAsProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:335)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:777)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.go(WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.java:222)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.ABWorkItemImpl.run(ABWorkItemImpl.java:159)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)

[5/21/13 10:42:26:241 MSD] 00000222 cem           W com.ibm.websphere.cem getEmitterFactory CEMEM0003E: The specified emitter factory was not found in JNDI. {0} 
[5/21/13 10:42:26:242 MSD] 00000222 LocalExceptio E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "invokeProcessSessionBean" on bean "BeanId(BPEContainer_qnode_server1#bpecontainer.jar#CScopeProvider, null)". Exception data: com.ibm.bpe.api.UnexpectedFailureException: CWWBA0010E: Unexpected exception during execution.
com.ibm.bpe.api.EngineStateObserverEventError: CWWBE0013E: An error occurred during the event handling of 'activityStarted' in the observer plug-in type 'com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.CEMStateObserverPlugin'.
com.ibm.websphere.cem.exception.EmitterFactoryCreationException: CEMEM0003E: The specified emitter factory was not found in JNDI. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: qcell/nodes/qnode/servers/server1, name: com/ibm/events/configuration/emitter/Default: First component in name events/configuration/emitter/Default not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0] 
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: qcell/nodes/qnode/servers/server1, name: com/ibm/events/configuration/emitter/Default: First component in name events/configuration/emitter/Default not found.
org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.handleNameNotFound(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:2519)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.getNextWsnOptimizedNamingContext(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:1270)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$3.run(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4738)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$3.run(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4733)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.retry(CommonHelpers.java:771)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.getTargetContext(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4732)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$LeafOperationData.<init>(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:5311)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.resolve_complete_info(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:2155)
    at com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming._NamingContextStub.resolve_complete_info(_NamingContextStub.java:538)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2809)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2805)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.retry(CommonHelpers.java:771)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.cosResolve(CNContextImpl.java:2803)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1802)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1761)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1512)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:644)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:166)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:180)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at com.ibm.websphere.cem.ECSEmitter$5.run(ECSEmitter.java:825)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:202)
    at com.ibm.websphere.cem.ECSEmitter.getEmitterFactory(ECSEmitter.java:822)
    at com.ibm.websphere.cem.ECSEmitter.getEmitter(ECSEmitter.java:905)
    at com.ibm.websphere.cem.ECSEmitter.<init>(ECSEmitter.java:138)
    at com.ibm.ws.monitoring.core.cei.ECSAccess.getECSEmitter(ECSAccess.java:108)
    at com.ibm.ws.monitoring.core.BaseMonitor.getECSEmitter(BaseMonitor.java:334)
    at com.ibm.bpe.monitor.MonitoredComponent.getECSEmitter(MonitoredComponent.java:248)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.EventHelper.getECSEmitter(EventHelper.java:107)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.ActivityInstanceEventTypeHandler.processBPELEvent(ActivityInstanceEventTypeHandler.java:1880)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.CEMSOPContextRestored.activityInstanceEvent(CEMSOPContextRestored.java:170)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.BpelStateObserverContextImpl.restoreContextAndFireActivityInstanceEvent(BpelStateObserverContextImpl.java:1455)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.CEMStateObserverPlugin.activityInstanceEvent(CEMStateObserverPlugin.java:444)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.BpelStateObserver.observe(BpelStateObserver.java:1562)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.BpelStateObserver.observeOrDelay(BpelStateObserver.java:1525)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.BpelStateObserver.activityStarted(BpelStateObserver.java:86)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelActivityState.setActivityState(BpelActivityState.java:469)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelActivityState.setActivityState(BpelActivityState.java:593)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelActivityState.setActivityState(BpelActivityState.java:117)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelActivityState.setActivityState(BpelActivityState.java:99)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelActivityKindScript.doActivate(BpelActivityKindScript.java:70)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelActivityStateInactive.activateOrSkip(BpelActivityStateInactive.java:280)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelEngineCore.continueControlLink(BpelEngineCore.java:291)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelContinueLinkMessage3.execute(BpelContinueLinkMessage3.java:88)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelEngine.onMessage(BpelEngine.java:1536)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.GenericAPIServicesImpl$7.run(GenericAPIServicesImpl.java:440)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.infrastructure.InfrastructureServicesSupportBean.runInCScopeTxClassLoaderContextsWithException(InfrastructureServicesSupportBean.java:167)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.infrastructure.EJSLocalStatelessInfrastructureServicesSupportBea_70e9f9d4.runInCScopeTxClassLoaderContextsWithException(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.infrastructure.InfrastructureServicesImpl.runInCScopeTxClassLoaderContextsWithException(InfrastructureServicesImpl.java:350)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.infrastructure.InfrastructureServicesImpl$2.run(InfrastructureServicesImpl.java:251)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.sca.AbstractBPCImplementationHandler.handleInvocationEnvironmentRequest(AbstractBPCImplementationHandler.java:197)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.sca.AbstractBPCImplementationHandler.processMessage(AbstractBPCImplementationHandler.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessageWithPCI(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:755)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessage(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:1607)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.ManagedMessageImpl.process(ManagedMessageImpl.java:980)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.webmodule.handler.WebModuleContextSwitchHandler.processMessage(WebModuleContextSwitchHandler.java:146)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessageWithPCI(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:766)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessage(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:1607)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.proxy.impl.ProxyInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandlerImpl.java:783)
    at $Proxy78.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.sca.InvocationEnvironmentProviderImpl.runInInvocationEnvironment(InvocationEnvironmentProviderImpl.java:158)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.infrastructure.InfrastructureServicesImpl.runInScaCScopeTxClassLoaderContextsWithException(InfrastructureServicesImpl.java:257)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.GenericAPIServicesImpl.bpc_onMessage(GenericAPIServicesImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.navigation.CScopeProviderBean$1.run(CScopeProviderBean.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:202)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.navigation.CScopeProviderBean.invokeProcessSessionBean(CScopeProviderBean.java:165)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.navigation.EJSLocalStatelessCScopeProvider_19c383f5.invokeProcessSessionBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.navigation.NavigationWorkObject4ContextSwitch.processV6EngineMessage(NavigationWorkObject4ContextSwitch.java:409)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.navigation.NavigationWorkObject4ContextSwitch.processNextMessage(NavigationWorkObject4ContextSwitch.java:302)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.navigation.NavigationWorkObject4ContextSwitch.run(NavigationWorkObject4ContextSwitch.java:142)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$RunProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:202)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:768)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.ExecutionContextImpl.go(ExecutionContextImpl.java:86)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.ProcessExecutionContextImpl$2.run(ProcessExecutionContextImpl.java:169)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:251)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.ProcessExecutionContextImpl.go(ProcessExecutionContextImpl.java:159)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.navigation.ProcessNavigationBean.processNextMessage(ProcessNavigationBean.java:345)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.navigation.EJSLocalStatelessProcessNavigation_0f2917d9.processNextMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.navigation.NavigationWorkObject4WorkMgrThread.run(NavigationWorkObject4WorkMgrThread.java:103)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$RunProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:224)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:495)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:131)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:89)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$DoAsProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:335)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:777)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.go(WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.java:222)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.ABWorkItemImpl.run(ABWorkItemImpl.java:159)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)

[5/21/13 10:42:26:266 MSD] 00000222 cem           W com.ibm.websphere.cem getEmitterFactory CEMEM0003E: The specified emitter factory was not found in JNDI. {0} 
[5/21/13 10:42:26:268 MSD] 00000222 LocalExceptio E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "invokeProcessSessionBean" on bean "BeanId(BPEContainer_qnode_server1#bpecontainer.jar#CScopeProvider, null)". Exception data: com.ibm.bpe.api.UnexpectedFailureException: CWWBA0010E: Unexpected exception during execution.
com.ibm.bpe.api.EngineStateObserverEventError: CWWBE0013E: An error occurred during the event handling of 'activityStarted' in the observer plug-in type 'com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.CEMStateObserverPlugin'.
com.ibm.websphere.cem.exception.EmitterFactoryCreationException: CEMEM0003E: The specified emitter factory was not found in JNDI. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: qcell/nodes/qnode/servers/server1, name: com/ibm/events/configuration/emitter/Default: First component in name events/configuration/emitter/Default not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0] 
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: qcell/nodes/qnode/servers/server1, name: com/ibm/events/configuration/emitter/Default: First component in name events/configuration/emitter/Default not found.
org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.handleNameNotFound(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:2519)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.getNextWsnOptimizedNamingContext(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:1270)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$3.run(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4738)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$3.run(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4733)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.retry(CommonHelpers.java:771)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.getTargetContext(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4732)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$LeafOperationData.<init>(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:5311)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.resolve_complete_info(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:2155)
    at com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming._NamingContextStub.resolve_complete_info(_NamingContextStub.java:538)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2809)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2805)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.retry(CommonHelpers.java:771)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.cosResolve(CNContextImpl.java:2803)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1802)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1761)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1512)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:644)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:166)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:180)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at com.ibm.websphere.cem.ECSEmitter$5.run(ECSEmitter.java:825)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:202)
    at com.ibm.websphere.cem.ECSEmitter.getEmitterFactory(ECSEmitter.java:822)
    at com.ibm.websphere.cem.ECSEmitter.getEmitter(ECSEmitter.java:905)
    at com.ibm.websphere.cem.ECSEmitter.<init>(ECSEmitter.java:138)
    at com.ibm.ws.monitoring.core.cei.ECSAccess.getECSEmitter(ECSAccess.java:108)
    at com.ibm.ws.monitoring.core.BaseMonitor.getECSEmitter(BaseMonitor.java:334)
    at com.ibm.bpe.monitor.MonitoredComponent.getECSEmitter(MonitoredComponent.java:248)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.EventHelper.getECSEmitter(EventHelper.java:107)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.ActivityInstanceEventTypeHandler.processBPELEvent(ActivityInstanceEventTypeHandler.java:1880)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.CEMSOPContextRestored.activityInstanceEvent(CEMSOPContextRestored.java:170)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.BpelStateObserverContextImpl.restoreContextAndFireActivityInstanceEvent(BpelStateObserverContextImpl.java:1455)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.CEMStateObserverPlugin.activityInstanceEvent(CEMStateObserverPlugin.java:444)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.BpelStateObserver.observe(BpelStateObserver.java:1562)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.BpelStateObserver.observeOrDelay(BpelStateObserver.java:1525)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.observer.BpelStateObserver.activityStarted(BpelStateObserver.java:86)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelActivityState.setActivityState(BpelActivityState.java:469)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelActivityState.setActivityState(BpelActivityState.java:593)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelActivityState.setActivityState(BpelActivityState.java:117)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelActivityState.setActivityState(BpelActivityState.java:99)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelActivityKindScript.doActivate(BpelActivityKindScript.java:70)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelActivityStateInactive.activateOrSkip(BpelActivityStateInactive.java:280)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelEngineCore.continueControlLink(BpelEngineCore.java:291)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelContinueLinkMessage3.execute(BpelContinueLinkMessage3.java:88)
    at com.ibm.bpe.engine.BpelEngine.onMessage(BpelEngine.java:1536)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.GenericAPIServicesImpl$7.run(GenericAPIServicesImpl.java:440)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.infrastructure.InfrastructureServicesSupportBean.runInCScopeTxClassLoaderContextsWithException(InfrastructureServicesSupportBean.java:167)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.infrastructure.EJSLocalStatelessInfrastructureServicesSupportBea_70e9f9d4.runInCScopeTxClassLoaderContextsWithException(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.infrastructure.InfrastructureServicesImpl.runInCScopeTxClassLoaderContextsWithException(InfrastructureServicesImpl.java:350)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.infrastructure.InfrastructureServicesImpl$2.run(InfrastructureServicesImpl.java:251)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.sca.AbstractBPCImplementationHandler.handleInvocationEnvironmentRequest(AbstractBPCImplementationHandler.java:197)
    at com.ibm.bpe.framework.sca.AbstractBPCImplementationHandler.processMessage(AbstractBPCImplementationHandler.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessageWithPCI(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:755)
```

Full log is here: http://pastebin.com/7eerEcS0

Comment: Standard BPEL doesn't allow for java snippets, so the problem you are having is likely very very specific to websphere. I wouldn't bet on getting an answer on this here. Maybe a more complete code snippet would help?

Comment: Same module works fine in the same environment under windows7. Problem occures only under Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be CEI configuration issue. You can disable all the CEI events and test it. Also uncheck default events if you have enabled events for the bpel under Event Monitor >> Global Event Settings?